# SSH bridge between two dynamic-ip pcs through third static-ip pc for jupyter notebook

Tags: ssh, jupyter, vpn

normally I use this kind of script (this is part of a larger bash script) to connect my pc to a static-ip pc and run a jupyter notebook remotely:

```
sudo fuser -k 8881/tcp
echo 'Port 8881 is free now'
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8881:localhost:8888 $username@$servername 
read -p 'SSH Tunnel created - Press enter to continue'
ssh $username@$servername 'nohup jupyter notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir="$notebookdir"'
wait
echo 'Please, wait some seconds.'
$nohup $browser http://localhost:8881/
```

And it works. But now I need to access a third pc that have a dynamic ip and I cant use services like dyndns. One good solution is to create a simple VPN like was done here https://superuser.com/questions/315523/ssh-connection-between-two-behind-nat-computers-through-third-public-ip-computer.

This means that I have to do in the remote pc (dynamic-ip pc):

```
ssh -R 20000:127.0.0.1:22 user@RemoteHost
```

On my local pc (which also have a dynamic-ip):

```
ssh -L 8000:127.0.0.1:20000 user@RemoteHost
```

And finally, if I do:

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 8000
```

This creates the "VPN". But now I'm a little lost on how to run the jupyter notebook forwarding a port in away that I can use the jupyter notebook of my remote pc on my local browser, using the remotehost with static-ip as a bridge.

Any suggestions or tips are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify it with your `~/.ssh/config` on your local pc

```
HOST remotehost
    hostname remotehost.tld
    user myuser

Host thirdparty
    hostname localhost
    port 20000
    LocalForward 8081 localhost:8080
    ProxyJump remotehost
```

Now you can do a simple

```
ssh thirdparty "nohup jupyter notebook --no-browser ..."
ssh -N thirdparty
$nohup $browser http://localhost:8881/
```

If you ssh to `thirdparty` this will use the remotehost as a jump box (ProxyJump) and the LocalFoward in the config automatically builds up the port forwarding to your jupyter notebook

Comment: Thank you jeb, work almost perfectly. The only thing is that ssh thirdparty "nohup jupyter notebook --no-browser ..." is not working (Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-noteboook` not found, I don't know why yet), I have to first do ssh -R 20000:127.0.0.1:22 user@RemoteHost  and start jupyter on the thirdparty remote pc (jupyter notebook --no-browser ...), after this I can run ssh -N thirdparty and open the notebook on my local pc, and so everything works (all computation is done on the thirdparty remote pc).